# PHP Stream ticker code

Tags: php, html, stream

I'm looking for a PHP script that tells me when a stream is live or not. Right now I wasn't able to find something that would help. So, I'm gonna wait as long as it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has built-in functionality that allows you to pull in a website and inspect its contents.

If the "stream" page looks different when it is "live" vs. when it is "not live", then you can check to see if the page has an HTML element on it (a div, video, Flash object, etc...), which will help you decide whether the stream is "live" or not.

```
//load the html
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
if($doc->getElementById('id-of-element-that-should-exist')
{
  //stream is live, do something
}
```

If this live "stream" is a video, often the element on the page will be a `<video>` or `<object>` tag. Look in the source for those, and find the ID of that element.

Comment: Can you please speak more clearly? It's kinda hard to understand what you are saying since I am new to PHP.

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit. If still un-clear, can you post an example of a stream that is "live" and one that is "not live"?

Comment: So, I'm using a Twitch TV embed code which has the element <object>.

Comment: Gotcha. So you're embedding this `<object>` on your own site, and want to be able to tell if that stream is live? If Twitch TV does not have a page that hosts this `<object>`, then your question falls more into the world of Flash, not PHP. Try posting a new question under Flash and link back to this question. Sorry, I don't know anything about Flash.

Comment: It's ok. I found something browsing Google at last. Thanks a lot! Sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: No worries :), glad you found something that works for you. If you don't mind accepting my answer as valid, then it's not a waste of time for anybody :).